# i have a problem save file in html and js

Tags: javascript, html, file, cmd, save

has written code in js

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.open('mynewfile2.txt', 'w', function (err, file) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Saved!');
});
```

when I run it with cmd it works and saves
but when I attach the js file in the html file and run the js file from the html page it doesn't work anymore
receives an error
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at plik.js:20

line 20 to: var fs = require('fs');

Comment: You can't access the users file-system from your website. This would be extremely dangerous, because any website could just access, change or delete your files. To access the file system you need to run a server.

Comment: You can't use Node.js-specific APIs inside a web browser.